# Copying cell value that starts with "=" sign and paste it as string/text

Tags: excel, vba

I got an exported Excel file with some values like: "=Min" or "=Min + 11op D3". (not a formula, just exported that way).

I'm doing lots of manipulations on the data and unfortunately, I cannot perform any change on the values start with the "=" sign.

so far I tried to change all cell starts with "=" to " '= " and still I cannot copy the cell content.

**I'm getting the "#NAME?" error in the cell where I pasted the copied value.**

I tried using that sub:

```
Sub changeEqualSign(colName As String)

   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim cell As Variant

   Set Rng = getHeadersRange(colName)

   Rng.Replace what:="=", Replacement:="'=", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
   :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
   , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

End Sub
```

any ideas on how to manage coping cells with the "=" sign?

I also tried the `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` and it didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try applying a Text format to cells containing strings formulas?

Comment: I tried to copy the cell value as .text or .value2.
I guess you mean changing the cell format, right?

Comment: Yes, i Mean the cell format. [Available number formats in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/available-number-formats-in-excel-0afe8f52-97db-41f1-b972-4b46e9f1e8d2). Try formatting cells into Text before pasting, and then pase the values.